# Xpath with Appium iOS for container with multiple elements

Tags: xpath, appium, appium-ios

I'm trying to access a container that has multiple elements with ids inside it but I can't seems to make it work like I do it for android.

This is what I have so far :

```
    try {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 3);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(
                By.xpath("//UIACollectionCell[UIAStaticText[contains(@name, 'section')] and UIAStaticText[contains(@name, 'title')]]")
        ));
        System.out.println("xpath w/ ids found");
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("xpath w/ ids not found");
    }
```

But it's working fine if I have just one text in it

```
    try {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 3);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(
                By.xpath("//UIACollectionCell/UIAStaticText[contains(@name, 'section')]")
        ));
        System.out.println("xpath w/ ids found");
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("xpath w/ ids not found");
    }
```

It seems that using the [ ] on my container makes it not understandable for some reason ...

Any idea ?

Thank you !

Comment: Could you please provide the page XML too, to verify the XPath match?

Comment: The xml elements are correct since it's working for one element.
The issue only comes out if you need a collectionCell with multiple text in it.

Comment: I cannot understand your locators if I do not have XML context.

Comment: it's 1 "UIACollectionCell" that contains 2 "UIAStaticText" with 2 different names

Answer (score 0):

just try like this:

```
By.xpath("//UIACollectionCell[UIAStaticText[contains(@name, 'section') and contains(@name, 'title')]]");
```

hope this helps and let me know what happens.

Comment: I don't want a 'Or' but a 'And' statement. I want it to have 2 staticText 1 that contains 'section' & 1 that contains 'title'

Comment: so use and instead of  or

Comment: this wouldn't work since you would search for a UIAStaticText that contains both 'section' & 'title' which is not possible. it's a UIACollectionCell that contains 2 UIAStaticText 1 with 'section' AND 1 with 'title'

Comment: actually i show you how to use and  between multiple xpath condition. try the update answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because you are asking the driver to wait for single element. If you want to wait for several then you must use `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By)` function.

Comment: It should work. It should give 1 element UIACollectionCell (that contains the 2 UIAStaticText") but still it's 1 element

Comment: `By.xpath("//UIACollectionCell[UIAStaticText[contains(@name, 'section')] and UIAStaticText[contains(@name, 'title')]]")` returns `UIACollectionCell` that contains 1 or more `UIAStaticText[contains(@name, 'title') and contains(@name, 'section')]`

Comment: `By.xpath("//UIACollectionCell/UIAStaticText[contains(@name, 'section')]")` returns all `UIAStaticText` that has attribute `name` containing `section`.